# How to minimize size of Angular Projects (on development) to upload them to a Dev. server?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am doing my first angular project and I have to upload it to a Development test server. Problem is that, an Angular project (event in default state) has so many files that it takes a lot of time to upload it.

I investigated and the .gitignore file seems only to be to avoid the commit of the files or folders specified there.

Could you please tell me if there is a way to minimize the number of needed files to upload and install or use them later, in local, in a safe way? Without risks of corrupting the project.

Comment: webpack or some other framework.

Comment: why dont you make a build and then upload to hosting server.

Comment: which version of angular?

Comment: Are you moving the node_modules folder?  If so, you shouldn't.  Everything in the node_modules packed into the files in your dist folder (assuming Angular 6 <=)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Angular CLI](https://angular.io/cli) you can get a production build by doing

```
npm run -- ng build --prod
```

in the project directory. This will create a minified, bundled version of your app in the `dist` folder, ready for upload. You will then need an http-server running to serve these files.

Answer (score 0):

As @yarz-tech suggested, the solution was to remove the node_modules each time I upload it. Then, when someone downloads it and wants to work with it again, must execute `npm install`. That allows npm to install all the dependencies our project needs, based on what is is specified on the `package.json` file, which appears not only for Angular projects, but for Node for example.

Thanks to everyone.